# Materialize CSS icon positioning in floating button

Tags: materialize

I'm trying to position an icon in the center of a floating button using materialize CSS. The icon is coming in the center, but its vertical position is not centered. Instead, it is placed at the top. Can someone tell how to bring it to the exact center of the button?

Comment: could you add code snippet to your question ?? That will make us more clear about your problem

Comment: <div class="container">
        <span>
       <h1> <i class="material-icons white-text btn-floating pulse center valign-wrapper waves-effect ">g_translate</i> </h1>
       </span>
    </div>

Comment: Posted an answer below check out if it is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
     <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container"> 
 <a class="btn-floating pulse btn-large waves-effect waves-light "><i class="material-icons">g_translate</i></a>
    </div>
       
</body>

</html>
```

Here is what you need. hope it will help!!

Comment: if it helped please help by voting up :)

Comment: I've already voted up but since I don't have more than 15 reputation, it won't show